# Is it possible to run openHAB and Z-Way-Server in parallel?

Tags: hardware, home-automation, zwave, razberry, openhab

I have a [RaZberry](http://razberry.z-wave.me/) Z-Wave module on my Raspbery GPIO pins and it works well. I use Raspian and java 8.

I use the Z-Way-Server and now I set up [openHAB](http://code.google.com/p/openhab/) version 1.3 with the new Z-Wave binding.

The question is: Can they work in parallel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they can't, since both uses Sigma Designs Serial API protocol to talk with the RaZberry board and that protocol requires the software to keep states. If two programs uses one tty port, only one (first to get the quatum time) will receives the message from the stick and the state in the second program will be inconsistent.

As an example, every message sent to the stick requires and ACK (acknowledge) message. If second program will receive this ACK, the first will feel RaZberry not to answer.

So, you need to choose only one.

Note that Z-Way-Server have a pretty good HTTP API to intercommunicate with other programs.